# PayPal oAuth2.0

Tags: paypal, oauth-2.0

- How does one retrieve the access token using the oAuth2.0 approach PayPal came up with ?
- Why does one have to invoke 2 (two) URL's when the login process is initialized (aka started) and how is this exactly done ?
- There is also the issue of the sandbox: assuming that one has the access token, can this token be used for the sandbox AND the real-time environments ?
- What is the actual applicability of the Access Token in regards to various API's ?

---

I'm using as a reference: 
https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/quick-start-guides/oauth-integration-paypal-access-getting-full

and I run into the following two statements which I cannot rationalize:

1) "When a user clicks the button, initiate the login process by calling the following URL (wrapped for readability):"

- Called URL:  identity.x.com/xidentity/resources/authorize

2) and below:
"For example, the URL to invoke the log-in function might resemble the following (wrapped for readability):"

- Called URL: identity.x.com/idaas/resources/authorize

---

For clarity purposes:

- The application is registered
- jQuery used (request is properly routed)
- I run the test with https://identity.x.com/xidentity/resources/authorize.

Comment: Just an FYI - the endpoint issue that I mentioned below (that I said I'd file a bug for) has been fixed on the documentation as of yesterday afternoon.

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I can answer your questions.  First off, when you mention the two URLs in the text and example:
identity.x.com/xidentity/resources/authorize &
identity.x.com/idaas/resources/authorize
I wanted to call out that the second URL in the example (identity.x.com/idaas/resources/authorize) is a typo and I will submit a request for the technical writer to make the adjustment to the documentation (my apologies for the confusion there).  With that said, let me get into your specific questions.

**How does one retrieve the access token using the oAuth2.0 approach PayPal came up with ?**

First, go to https://devportal.x.com/ and sign up for a PayPal Access application to get your keys and application ID that you will need in the PayPal Access process.

The OAuth 2 process basically has three steps to it:

1. You redirect the user to the authorize URL that you mentioned in order to sign in to PayPal (with the appropriate parameters attached to the URL).  See https://github.com/paypal/paypal-access/blob/master/oauth2-php-ppaccess/index.php for that process.
2. When the user signs in they are redirected to a redirect_url you supply in step 1.  In the URL after redirect, a code parameter will be available on the URL query string.  Take that and send an HTTP POST request to PayPal to exchange the code for an access token (see https://github.com/paypal/paypal-access/blob/master/oauth2-php-ppaccess/complete.php lines 4-11)
3. Once you have the access token, you can make an HTTP GET request to the PayPal profile endpoint with the access token supplied as a URL parameter to get the profile of the user (https://github.com/paypal/paypal-access/blob/master/oauth2-php-ppaccess/complete.php lines 13-19).

With all of that said, I would actually recommend that you use OpenID Connect instead of OAuth 2.  OpenID Connect has endpoints to allow users to log out and it will be the protocol that the PayPal Access team supports the most.  Here are two samples that will show you how to build those:

- https://github.com/paypal/paypal-access/tree/master/openid-connect-php-ppaccess
- https://github.com/paypal/paypal-access/tree/master/openid-connect-python-ppaccess

**Why does one have to invoke 2 (two) URL's when the login process is initialized (aka started) and how is this exactly done ?**
See above regarding both of these.

**There is also the issue of the sandbox: assuming that one has the access token, can this token be used for the sandbox AND the real-time environments ?**
Yes, the same token can be used for both sandbox and production.  I should note here that currently you cannot use any sandbox logins (test users) to log into PayPal Access.  That feature should be available shortly, so for the time being you can use a real PayPal account for access.

**What is the actual applicability of the Access Token in regards to various API's ?**
Think of the access token as a skeleton key for the APIs.  It's the code that basically tells the API that the user who is giving away their information has granted the application permission to do so, and that the application itself is valid.

I hope that all helps,
Jon